# SQL Query to get the Max Date of a certain Status and subract that from the Max Date of another Status

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, metrics

An example would be.. Say a ticket is in New status.  I want to get the MAX Date of New Status and the Max date of Completed Status and calculate the difference between the MAX Completed Status from the MAX New Status

ex.

```
SELECT t.ID,
       MAX(update_date) WHERE t.status = 'New' start_time,
       MAX(update_date) WHERE t.status = 'Completed' stop_time,
DATEDIFF(second, MAX(update_date), MAX(update_date)) elapsed_sec
FROM xxx.dbo t
GROUP BY t.ID;
```

Thank you so much,

P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    t.id
    ,DATEDIFF(second, start_time, stop_time) elapsed_sec
FROM (
    SELECT
        ID,
        (SELECT MAX(update_date) from xxx.dbo WHERE status = 'New' AND ID=t2.ID) start_time,
        (SELECT MAX(update_date) from xxx.dbo WHERE status = 'Completed' AND ID=t2.ID) stop_time
    FROM xxx.dbo t2
) t
```

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH!!  Extremely thankful!  Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing this using condition aggregation and not with correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT t.ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.status = 'New' THEN update_date END) as start_time,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.status = 'Completed' THEN update_date END) as stop_time,
       MAX(update_date) WHERE t.status = 'Completed' stop_time,
       DATEDIFF(second,
                MAX(CASE WHEN t.status = 'New' THEN update_date END),
                MAX(CASE WHEN t.status = 'Completed' THEN update_date END)
               ) as elapsed_sec
FROM xxx.dbo t
GROUP BY t.ID;
```

Comment: Idle curiosity: Why do you suggest this as opposed to correlated subqueries?

Comment: The correlated subqueries require more work.  You are already doing an aggregation to remove duplicates.  There is no reason to do additional work -- even if an index is available -- for identifying the information you want.  And, if you don't have the right indexes, then the performance difference will be quite noticeable.